# adding event handlers on dynamically created WPF controls

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application and it is using dynamic WPF controls. How do I add event like button or image OnResize?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by adding events?. Do you want something like this button.Click += button_Clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could hook up an event handler to an event of the `Button` or `Image` using the += syntax:

```
 Image image = new Image();
 image.SizeChanged += (s, e) => { /* handle event */ };
```